# Active = False ante de iniciar uma aplicação Delphi

Tags: banco-de-dados, delphi, conexão

Sempre que trabalhamos no `Datamodule` no componente de conexão, ativamos para fazer testes e afins. Acontece que, se esquecermos de desativar quando compilamos, pode dar erro quando enviamos para o cliente devido ao IP ou usuário e senha serem diferentes no desenvolvimento e produção.

Eu utilizo o componente `TZConnection` da Zeos, mas acho que isso vale pra todos.

Gostaria de saber se tem como desativar o componente antes ou no `onCreate` do `form`. Já vi que no evento `onCreate` não adianta, pois ele ativa a conexão antes mesmo do `onCreate`.

Answer (score 4):

Resolvi tratando no evento BeforeConnect do componente, ali eu seto todas as variaveis referente a conexao levando em conta se é Desenvolvimento ou Produção.

Answer (score 2):

desde a faculdade aprendi a realizar esse tipo de procedimento no evento OnShow ao invés do OnCreate.

e outra dica que sempre utilizo é deixar um DataModule padrão no servidor salvo e outro para uso diario nas demais maquinas, ai quando vou compilar os fontes sempre acaba pegando o padrao, ai esse tipo de erro por esquecimento acaba não ocorrendo.

Comment: Então @Leonardo Maciel, eu resolvi tratando no BeforeConnect do componente, assim não importa se eu esquecer como Active, pois eu seto as configurações antes de ele conectar.